# Only black screen in my UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I have two View Controllers. In the first one i have a button and when you click it you need to display a Web Page in a second View Controller. When I click the button, I see only a black screen.

Here is TabulkaViewController.m code:

```
#import "TabulkaViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface TabulkaViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabulkaViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _hbutton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    _hbutton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];        
}
- (IBAction)hbutton:(id)sender

{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
   WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Apple"];
    [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is code of WebViewController.h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
    {
        NSURL *theURL;
        NSString *theTitle;
        IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
        IBOutlet UINavigationItem *webTitle;

    }

    - (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
    - (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string;
    - (IBAction) done:(id)sender;

    @end
```

And here is code of WebViewController.m:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webTitle.title = theTitle;
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObject];}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string {
    if( self = [super init] ) {
        theURL = url;
        theTitle = string;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self initWithURL:url andTitle:nil];
}

- (IBAction) done:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView stopLoading];
}
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Comment: in viewDidLoad, after creating requestObject, try `NSLog(@"%@, %@", theURL, requestObject);`and post the results.

Comment: Result is: Tabulkaprvku[2983:60b] http://apple.com, <NSURLRequest: 0x8c2ebb0> { URL: http://apple.com }

Comment: ok, thats good. but i dont see you instantiating the webview anywhere. try `NSLog(@"%@", webView);` before `[webView loadRequest: requestObject]`. i assume it might be nil.

Comment: Result is: 2014-05-29 18:36:36.353 Tabulkaprvku[3154:60b] (null)

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the webView at some point. I suggest you change your viewDidLoad to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webTitle.title = theTitle;
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObject];
}
```

Since your webView is `null`at the start of the method, it needs to be created before you can load any Requests. Just declaring it in the header file is not enough, thats why you need `webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];`.

EDIT:
Of course, you could also put that line into your ìnitWithURL:andTitle: method, where the other instantiations take place.

Comment: I tried put the line into the  - (void)viewDidLoad and now I have result: Tabulkaprvku[3325:60b] <UIWebView: 0xa17e2c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0xa180b70>>

Comment: @Alien - Ok, thats great. But it sounds like your problem didnt go away? Did you connect the outlet to a Webview in the XIB/Storyboard?

Comment: Y I have connect webView with Web View in Outlet (I use Storyboard) :(

Comment: @Alien - Well, then the problem is not in the code you posted. (at least, not anymore). Good luck solving this.